# Extracting products models for products description text (not reviews, unstructured text)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm looking for a method that will help me with this task. I'm familiar with NER but in this case it wont help me, the sentences are short and NER doesn't work well with it.

The input is products description (from Amazon for example, see the marked line in the image below), not something that POS tagging might help with.

[image]

An example:

```
1. Apple iPhone 6 64GB White
2. iRobot Scooba 390 Floor Scrubbing Robot
3. Samsung UN60J6200 60-Inch TV with HW-J450 Soundbar
```

And the results I'm looking for:

```
1. Brand: Apple, Model: iPhone 6, Features: 64GB, White
2. Brand: iRobot, Model: Scooba 390, Features: Floor Scrubbing Robot
3. Brand: Samsung , Model: UN60J6200 , Features: 60-Inch, HW-J450 Soundbar
```

This is a really difficult problem for me and till now Iv'e solved it in a non-generic way and just by using NLP methods. So I wonder if there's a way of training a model for such task.

Some points I want to add:

- The brand name is not always at the beginning of the sentence
- Some times the entire sentence contains only small letters.
- In many cases different brands use really similar models for their products (iPhone 6s and Galaxy S6 for example).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem above, if so, are you willing to share the details ? Thanks!

Comment: @cherit Nope, sorry

Comment: As these product titles does not follow any format, i would suggest to extract the information from Product information/Technical Details section if possible